# How do I close the CMD when I enter a certain value in perl?

Tags: perl

I am currently making a program that will *eventually* be able to auto start when I sign onto my computer and will allow me to select from a variety of programs to start. I currently have two (just started it). Anyway, I was wondering, because it is being run thru CMD, how can I have the program close CMD when I enter a certain value. My code:

```
print "What would you like to run? (1 for Chrome and 2 for Calculator \"e\" for exit)  \n";
my $prog_run = <STDIN>;

if ($prog_run == 1){
#Chrome Function
system('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"');
}elsif ($prog_run == 2){
#Calculator Function
system('"C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe"');
}elsif ($prog_run == "e"){
  #Exit Fucntion
  print "Exiting........";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
}elsif ($prog_run == "e"){
```

`==` is the numeric comparison operator; it only works correctly on numbers. Since `"e"` is a string, you will need to use the string comparison operator, `eq`, to compare something with it:

```
} elsif ($prog_run eq "e") {
```

However, the line you read from standard input will have a newline on it by default. You can either include this in your string (`"e\n"`), or `chomp $prog_run;` beforehand to strip off the newline.

Anyways.

If you're in a loop, you can use `last` to exit out of it. Alternatively, you can use `exit` to make the whole Perl process… well, exit.

Comment: Is there a way to close the whole CMD? or just the script?

Comment: Not really. That isn't an expected behavior for any program.